# SpringApplicationBuilder Parent-Child hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a parent-child architecture for my Spring Boot application in which there is a separate child for each config file found in a directory.

I am trying to accomplish this using the `SpringApplicationBuilder` and failing.

At the moment, my `main` logic looks something like:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ParentConfiguration.class)
                .properties(Collections.singletonMap("application.dataTypeCount", propertySourceList.size()))
                .logStartupInfo(false);

// for each property source, add it to a child application and start that application
for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : propertySourceList) {
            parentBuilder
                    .child(ChildConfiguration.class)
                    .initializers(context -> context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource))
                    .run(args);
}
```

This works pretty well at the moment.

However, I don't have the shutdown behavior I'd like. If *any* of the children fail to start up, I want every application to stop. What's the best way to achieve this? Seems like there should be something higher level than twiddling around with `ApplicationEventListener`.

Comment: Are you using WAR deployment or fat JAR with embedded servlet container?

Comment: It doesn't actually listen for HTTP -- incoming data is all over AMQP -- which is to say, there's no servlet, but I am using `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.

Comment: Very interesting question!